# Find total hours of sunlight in a day at a certain latitude

Tags: visible-light

Im trying to find the total hours of sunlight on 15 August at a latitude of 54 o N.

Im using the Declination formula:
[image: declination][1]]

```
15 August = 226 days
```

And working through the formula:

```
23.45 sin (360/365 * (226 + 284))
23.45 sin (.986 * (510))
23.45 sin (502.86)
23.45 * 0.2037
4.777

So declination = 4.777
```

Now I try to find the hour angle with:

[image]

```
w =  cos ^-1 (-tan(4.7777)tan(54)) 
= cos ^-1 (15.289 * 0.673) 
= cos^-1 (10.289)
```

This give me an error since cos^-1(arccos) expects a value between -1 and +1.

After this I was going to divide the result of w by 15 (which is 360/24) to find the hour of sunrise. However I seem to be making a basic mistake along the way. What could it be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your calculation of the hour angle $\omega_s$ is wrong.
I get
$$\begin{align}
\omega_s&=\cos^{-1}(-\tan\delta\tan\phi) \\
&=\cos^{-1}(-\tan(4.777°)\tan(54°)) \\
&=\cos^{-1}(-0.0836\cdot 1.376) \\
&=\cos^{-1}(-0.115) \\
&=96.6°
\end{align}$$
May be you forgot to switch your calculator to degrees instead of radiants.

Comment: you're correct, facepalm!